# How can we block http request on Wildfly server based on url pattern?

Tags: java, jboss, server, wildfly-8

I have a weired secnerio to tackle with. We are using Wildfly 8.2.0 final as our server for javaEE Application. We want to restrict or block certain https request identified by url pattern on certain https port. For example:

I have configured two https listener at different port(8184,8443). what i want is that all request in the form https://servername:8184/synws/ should be blocked while the request https://servername:8443/synws/ should be allowed.

how can we achieve this in wildfly server. and the request are all jax-rs web service calls.

Comment: Just a guesswork, in your web.xml ,  could not add a  <security-constraint>  with the matching  url-pattern and with a no existing role ?

Comment: I want to do it with wildfly port not within application

Comment: Sorry but I think It's not a good idea. You will create undesirable network coupling.

Why don't you secure this server since the tools provided by the server or the application hosted on it ?

Comment: How can be we do it? please give some reference for this

Comment: What is your server type and the application type hosted behind   https://servername:8184/synws/  ?